# SPARK AR my pulse patch does not let me turn on and off on the checkbox

Tags: spark-ar-studio

I added a Pulse patch but it doesn't allow me to click on or off in the checkbox, it's greyed out. please help?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

From the information you shared, I'm assuming a hypothesis that you have a Pulse patch that has some kind of input attached at the On/Off input and this probably is why you can't click at the checkbox to turn it on or off.